# Reducing a large stream without stack overflowing

Tags: scala, stream, range, stack-overflow, reduce

1I'm trying to make a limit-less factorial function (just out of curiosity.) This works for large `n` (tried up to 100000 and it seems to work, although I can't check the output value for correctness because, well, it's LARGE!)

```
(BigInt(1) to n).reduceRight(_*_)
```

But I'm afraid that the whole `BigInt(1) to n` range might be in memory, while I just need it element by element for `reduceRight`. Taking a look at Scala's standard library code it looks like `BigInt(1) to n` actually outputs the whole `Range` and not a lazy `Stream` but I found `Stream.range` which I can use like this (notice the `n+1`, stream range is exclusive)

```
Stream.range[BigInt](BigInt(1), BigInt(n+1)).reduceRight(_*_)
```

It works for `n=10000` (for some reason it takes a little bit longer! which makes me think that maybe the normal range is actually a `Stream` too?) but for `n=100000` I get this stack overflow

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.math.BigInteger.add(Unknown Source)
    at scala.math.BigInt.$plus(BigInt.scala:161)
    at scala.math.Numeric$BigIntIsIntegral$class.plus(Numeric.scala:28)
    at scala.math.Numeric$BigIntIsIntegral$.plus(Numeric.scala:40)
    at scala.math.Numeric$BigIntIsIntegral$.plus(Numeric.scala:40)
    at scala.math.Numeric$Ops.$plus(Numeric.scala:208)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$$anonfun$range$1.apply(Stream.scala:695)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$$anonfun$range$1.apply(Stream.scala:695)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:634)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:626)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.reduceRight(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:130)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.reduceRight(Stream.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.reduceRight(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:131)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.reduceRight(Stream.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.reduceRight(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:131)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.reduceRight(Stream.scala:47)
    ...
```

It's obvious that `reduceRight` is calling itself like this

```
reduceRight(reduceRight(first, second, op), third, op)...
```

And thus the stack overflow. I assume it's not tail-call optimized because it first reduces and then operates prior to returning the value, so it can't be optimized. How could I approach this problem then? Should I ditch the functional approach and aim for custom imperative-style code for reducing?

What strikes me as a very odd thing is that the `(BigInt(1) to n).reduceRight(_*_)` does not overflow for large `n` while almost the same using a stream does... What's going on here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`reduceLeft` is implemented to compute as it goes on streams (and it calls in order).  You can verify as follows:

```
Stream.range(1,10).map(i => print(i)).reduceLeft((a,b) => println("r"))
```

Or you can use tail recursion:

```
final def fac(n: BigInt, prod: BigInt = BigInt(1)): BigInt = {
  if (n<2) prod else fac(n-1,prod*n)
}
```

(as Travis points out, it'd be faster to multiply the small numbers first, which would take an extra line).

Comment: See my comment in the other answer (applies here too.) Also: I'd like to avoid the common factorial implementation using TCR since this is meant as an exercise for using lazy ranges.

Comment: @kaoD - It doesn't need the range and doesn't start from the last element.  See example (paste into REPL).

Answer (score 8):

You are correct that your first solution [will create a list in memory](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.scala#L167) to store the reversed sequence. You could simply use `reduceLeft` (which doesn't have that problem on ranges), but that will pass through the range in the opposite direction. If for some reason you want to start at the large end but keep the laziness of `reduceLeft`, you can create a backwards `Range`:

```
def fact(n: Int) = (BigInt(n) to 1 by -1).reduceLeft(_ * _)
```

There may be [other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7863859/334519) you can easily optimize this function.

Comment: Great ideas for optimization. Thanks!

Comment: You have the order backwards.  In-order is faster than reverse-order, and `foldLeft` does it in the order you ask for.

Comment: @Rex: actually, if the cost of `BigInt` multiplication is proportional to the product of the number of digits of the two numbers, then neither direction has an advantage, right? In any case I've edited the answer to make this a non-issue.

Comment: @TravisBrown In my very limited testing, the direction you're proposing is about 30% slower than the reverse (increasing) direction.

Comment: @Travis - You were right the first time about the performance; you were just wrong about the evaluation order.  For example: 2*2*2*1000 has cost 1+1+4 in forward order and 4+4+4 in reverse order, using your metric.

Answer (score 4):

Try using `reduceLeft` instead. `reduceRight` starts from the end of the stream and thus forces every element to be evaluated — exactly what you wanted to avoid.

Comment: Thought of that too but, wouldn't it need the whole `Range` to begin with? IIRC, `reduceLeft` starts from the last element, but the whole `Range` has to be computed for the last element to exist (which is actually what I don't want to.)

Comment: `reduceLeft` starts on the left part, so at the first element, like `foldLeft`.

Comment: Yep, I was just looking at `TraversableOnce` and saw it. I mistakenly took `Right` as direction of evaluation, not beginning of it. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, this works faster for me: `Stream.range(BigInt(1), BigInt(n)).par.reduce(_*_)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def fac (n: BigInt=1, m:BigInt=1): Stream[BigInt] = 
  Stream.cons (n, fac (n * m, m+1))

fac().take (10).toList
res27: List[BigInt] = List(1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880)
```

works well with `take(10000).toList` too.

Comment: Define this as a val and it'd take a lot less to compute (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659127/how-to-fix-my-fibonacci-stream-in-scala)