# Optimizing bigint calls

Tags: python, optimization, d

I am currently using the book 'Programming in D' for learning D. I tried to solve a problem of summing up the squares of numbers from 1 to 10000000. I first made a functional approach to solve the problem with the map and reduce but as the numbers get bigger I have to cast the numbers to bigint to get the correct output.

```
  long num = 10000001;
  BigInt result;
  result = iota(1,num).map!(a => to!BigInt(a * a)).reduce!((a,b) => (a + b));
  writeln("The sum is : ", result);
```

The above takes 7s to finish when compiled with dmd -O . I profiled the program and most of the time is wasted on BigInt calls. Though the square of the number can fit into a long I have to typecast them to bigint so that reduce function sums and returns the appropriate sum. The python program takes only 3 seconds to finish it. When num = 100000000 D program gets to 1 minute and 13 seconds to finish. Is there a way to optimize the calls to bigint. The products can themselves be long but they have to be typecasted as bigint objects so that they give right results from reduce operations. I tried pushing the square of the numbers into a bigint array but its also slower. I tried to typecast all the numbers as Bigint

```
auto bigs_map_nums = iota(1,num).map!(a => to!BigInt(a)).array;
auto bigs_map = sum(bigs_map_nums.map!(a => (a * a)).array);
```

But its also slower. I read the answers at [How to optimize this short factorial function in scala? (Creating 50000 BigInts)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863496/how-to-optimize-this-short-factorial-function-in-scala-creating-50000-bigints). Is it a problem with the implementation of multiplication for bigger integers in D too ? Is there a way to optimize the function calls to BigInt ?

python code :

```
timeit.timeit('print sum(map(lambda num : num * num, range(1,10000000)))',number=1)
333333283333335000000
3.58552622795105
```

The code was executed on a dual-core 64 bit linux laptop with 2 GB RAM.
python : 2.7.4
dmd : DMD64 D Compiler v2.066.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without range coolness: `foreach(x; 0 .. num) result += x * x;`

With range cool(?)ness:

```
import std.functional: reverseArgs;
result = iota(1, num)
    .map!(a => a * a)
    .reverseArgs!(reduce!((a, b) => a + b))(BigInt(0) /* seed */);
```

The key is to avoid `BigInt`ing every element, of course.

The range version is a little slower than the non-range one. Both are significantly faster than the python version.

Edit: Oh! Oh! It can be made much more pleasant with `std.algorithm.sum`:

```
result = iota(1, num)
    .map!(a => a * a)
    .sum(BigInt(0));
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain why you used BigInt(0) in sum and reduce. How does it make the process to promote to BigInt only when needed?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It made the programs around 7 times faster and faster than python too :) It will be very helpful if you could explain the magic you did there with both reduce and why you used reverse args. The sum version looks very elegant too.. :) please add a little more detail as I am newbie to D. But in profiler i can see bigint calls. How is this faster?

Answer (score 5):

The python code is not equivalent to the D code, in fact it does a lot less.

Python uses an int, then it promotes that int to long() when the result is bigger than what can be stored in an int() type. Internally, (at least CPython) uses a long number to store integer bigger than 256, which is at least 32bits. Up until that overflow normal cpu instructions can be used for the multiplication which are quite faster than bigint multiplication.

D's BigInt implementation treats the numbers as BigInt from the start and uses the expensive multiplication operation from 1 until the end. Much more work to be done there.

It's interesting how complicated the multiplication can be when we talk about BigInts.

The D implementation is

https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/phobos/blob/v2.066.1/std/internal/math/biguintcore.d#L1246

Python starts by doing

```c
static PyObject *
int_mul(PyObject *v, PyObject *w)
{
    long a, b;
    long longprod;                      /* a*b in native long arithmetic */
    double doubled_longprod;            /* (double)longprod */
    double doubleprod;                  /* (double)a * (double)b */

    CONVERT_TO_LONG(v, a);
    CONVERT_TO_LONG(w, b);
    /* casts in the next line avoid undefined behaviour on overflow */
    longprod = (long)((unsigned long)a * b);

    ... //check if we have overflowed


    {
        const double diff = doubled_longprod - doubleprod;
        const double absdiff = diff >= 0.0 ? diff : -diff;
        const double absprod = doubleprod >= 0.0 ? doubleprod :
                              -doubleprod;
        /* absdiff/absprod <= 1/32 iff
           32 * absdiff <= absprod -- 5 good bits is "close enough" */
        if (32.0 * absdiff <= absprod)
            return PyInt_FromLong(longprod);
        else
            return PyLong_Type.tp_as_number->nb_multiply(v, w);
    }
}
```

and if the number is bigger than what a long can hold it does a karatsuba multiplication. Implementation in :

http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/longobject.c (k_mul function)

The equivalent code would wait to use BigInts until they are no native data types that can hold the number in question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there any way to do the similar thing of automatically promoting numbers only when necessary like python in D? Is it implementation dependent?

Comment: I am not sure if there's an automatic/clever way to do it but if I were to try it ,I'd start with a custom type DynInt, implementing the "interface" of a BigInt and on mul I'd use almost the same code with python to promote the stored value to a BigInt

Comment: Thanks. I accepted the answer and the program is around 7 times faster than previous version. But i couldn't grasp the usage of bigint in sum and reverseArgs. I requested the op to add explanation but couldn't get it. Could you please explain it.

Comment: reverseArgs!(reduce!((a, b) => a + b))(BigInt(0) /* seed */)

If we read it from the inside, we specialize a reduce function that does a sum. Then for the reduce(a, b), we change it via reverseArgs to reduce(b,a).

But why, you may ask ?

The reduce as is, it takes (MapResult!(..something), BigInt) as arguments and we want to pass BigInt as first argument to force everything to use BigInt addition (via the seed).

Comment: Why do we add bigint to it. Why do we reverse the arguments. Addition is commutative.

Comment: I pressed enter in the previous comment without completing it.. Does the full comment clears it out ?

Comment: Thanks. So the bigint 0 is passed first as b and then the squares are passed into it with all numbers promoted to bigint. I did the same explicitly by mapping all the numbers as bigint. What difference does it make in having all numbers as bigint and making all the intermediate results casted as bigint. They are all bigints while addition. Why does efficiency vary?

Comment: If you check the following https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/phobos/blob/v2.066.1/std/internal/math/biguintcore.d#L1199 you'll see that there is a more optimized overload of addition that takes BigInt, ulong. By converting everything to BigInt from the begining you force the non-trivial BigInt + BigInt addition

Comment: Will check. Thanks a lot for your patient help :)

Answer (score 4):

DMD's backend does not emit highly optimized code. For fast programs, compile with GDC or LDC.

On my computer, I get these timings:

```
Python:                    3.01
dmd   -O -inline -release: 3.92
ldmd2 -O -inline -release: 2.14
```

Comment: Thanks . As the value of num increases the timing gets large with dmd taking 1 minute 15 sconds. Apart from the compiler level change could there be any optimization done for the bigint calls ?